# Reading two files at same time, each with header lines to skip

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have two .txt files, each has 13 lines of header information that I need to skip.

I am combining them into one file, but this is not working because it doesn't skip the 2nd lot of header lines.

```
    DELIMITER = '\t';
    %HEADERLINES = 13;

    % Import the file

    system('copy A.txt+B.txt C.txt')

    newData1 = importdata('C.txt', DELIMITER, HEADERLINES);

    % Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
    vars = fieldnames(newData1);
    for i = 1:length(vars)
        assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
    end
```

Comment: Seems like you should import them separately, remove the headers and then combine them. Headers don't magically put themselves on top when appending text.

Comment: How can I join data like this? Read them both in and then: newData1 = join(A,B);? This gives an error also.

Comment: I don't have the matlab knowledge to answer that. But that is indeed the basic idea. A quick look at the docs leads me to the wild guess of `cat(1,A,B)` but I might be very wrong about this. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html

Comment: Why is HEADERLINES commented out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
% Read in the two files separately into matrices (skipping the header)
dat_a = dlmread('A.txt', DELIMITER, HEADERLINES, 0);
dat_b = dlmread('B.txt', DELIMITER, HEADERLINES, 0);

% Combine and write to the new file
dlmwrite('C.txt', [dat_a; dat_b], DELIMITER);
```

Checkout the docs ([dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) and  [dlmwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)) for more info.